# How to transform time from one timezone to another, ignoring local timezone?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have a date formatted like this '2018/11/17 13:30', but unfortunately it is from another timezone. I know the initial timezone and target timezone, and wanna to transform date and time from one to another correctly. It looks like simple task, especially using moment library, but after reading docs I still didn't figure out how to do it right. Will be glad to any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) to convert between two zones.

```js
let date = "2018/11/17 13:30"

// make date-time local to LA
let d = moment.tz(date, "YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm", "America/Los_Angeles")

console.log("L.A", d.format('LT'))

// convert to Chicago
console.log("Chicago:", d.tz("America/Chicago").format('LT'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.23/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```